# Помогите с regExp js для такого примера

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
"{
   \"definitions\":  {
     \"form\":  {
       \"type\":  \"object\",
       \"properties\":  {
         \"num\":  {
           \"type\":  \"string\" 
        },
         \"guid\":  {
           \"type\":  \"string\" 
        },
         \"vibor\":  {
           \"type\":  \"string\",
           \"enum\": [
            \"inn\",
             \"ogrn\"
          ] 
        } 
      },
       \"required\":  [
         \"num\",
         \"guid\",
         \"vibor\" 
      ] 
    } 
  },
   \"type\":  \"object\",
   \"properties\":  {
     \"requestName\":  {
       \"type\":  \"string\",
       \"enum\": [
        \"VS00050v003-FNS001\"
      ] 
    },
     \"isTest\":  {
       \"type\":  \"boolean\" 
    },
     \"form\":  {
       \"$ref\":  \"# definitions form\" 
    } 
  },
   \"required\":  [
     \"requestName\",
     \"isTest\",
     \"form\" 
  ] 
}"
```

как убрать обратные слэши? Были еще и символы переноса строк и табуляции, но их я убрал `/[\t\n\"]+/g`

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse("{ \"definitions\": { \"form\": { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"num\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"guid\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"vibor\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"enum\":[\"inn\", \"ogrn\"] } }, \"required\": [ \"num\", \"guid\", \"vibor\" ] } }, \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"requestName\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"enum\":[\"VS00050v003-FNS001\"] }, \"isTest\": { \"type\": \"boolean\" }, \"form\": { \"$ref\": \"# definitions form\" } }, \"required\": [ \"requestName\", \"isTest\", \"form\" ] }"))`

Comment: Странная тенденция, все пытаются json разобрать ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev "Ребята, не стоит вскрывать эту тему. Вы молодые, шутливые, вам все легко."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поиск всех обратных слэшей

```
/\\/g
```